# Modbus Device Register Mapping - pymodbus

Tags: python, fastapi, modbus, pymodbus

I´m trying to build an FastAPI Python App where I can read data from different Modbus Slave Device´s (Mostly Inverters). I managed to read the data from the inverter.

I have following Modbus Interface Definitions for the Inverter:
https://support.huawei.com/view/PdfRead/EDOC1100050690/SUPE_DOC/6001/document.pdf

Is there a clean way to map the register data from the device to a internal variable.
After the Mapping there should be a Object which contains following data:

- **Name** of the register.
- **Type** of the register.
- **Address** of the register.
- **Value**  of the register.
- **Unit** where the register comes from.

I there a clean way to do it by code or should it be done with an csv file where the definitions are mapped?

Comment: There are probably 100 answers to this and none more correct than than any other.  I have writtn lots of modbus code, most of mine is based on this: Create Python classes that define registers which then instance clases to interpret and interact with the data, but that's just one way and would not answer this question as you ask it.  At the top level is a dictionary of class instances.

Comment: So you mean the mapping should be done via code? Do you have an github example for such a mapping? I thought the solution for this problem is following class by pymodbus "BinaryPayloadDecoder" but that is not what I searched for.

Comment: Python can be used to describe any data structure.  There is some gravity in using some sort of 'config' file like YAML or (given it's being adoped by Python 11) TOML.  Depends on who is maintaining it and how it will be used in the field. i.e. do they know Python or not? You could go as far as a SQLite database if you wanted.  As I said there is no one correct answer to the question as it's too broad.

Comment: Without giving away propretary code I can't supply an example.  I don't think I've ever submitted anyting or know of any examples you can use as a basis.  I would suggest narrowing your question by supplying some requirements, limits and use cases of your project.  In your view what features an attributes are required make one solution any better than another?

Comment: Suggestion: Take a look at Python Dataclasses.  That could easily be used within what you describe.

Comment: Thank´s for the hint, after lookup i will face the approach with dataclasses.